# AWS Athena: How to escape reserved word column name and cast to integer

Tags: sql, casting, amazon-athena

I have a column named 'timestamp' which is a reserved word. I need to select the column then cast it as an integer to perform the query below. I can successfully perform a simple select of the column data. It is only when I try to cast the value as an integer that the error is returned.

I have tried to escape the reserved word using backticks and double quotes as suggested in the [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/reserved-words.html) without success.

**Query with backticks:**

```
SELECT `timestamp`
FROM my_table
WHERE from_unixtime(cast(`timestamp` as integer)) >= date_add('day', -7, now())
```

**Error:**

```
Queries of this type are not supported
```

**Query with double quotes:**

```
SELECT "timestamp"
FROM my_table
WHERE from_unixtime(cast("timestamp" as integer)) >= date_add('day', -7, now())
```

**Error:**

```
INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Cannot cast '' to INT
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not your escaping logic, but that your dataset contains empty strings in the timestamp column which can not be casted. You can avoid that, by filtering out the empty string records.

```
SELECT "timestamp"
FROM (SELECT "timestamp" from my_table where "timestamp" != '')
WHERE from_unixtime(cast("timestamp" as integer)) >= date_add('day', -7, now())
```

Comment: Now that you point that out, the error is very clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `cast` you can use [`try_cast`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conversion.html#try_cast) which returns `null` in case of unsuccessful cast (empty string can't be turned into `integer`), which will result in the where condition evaluated to false:

```sql
with dataset(col) as (
    values (''),
    ('1659648600')
)

select *
from dataset
where from_unixtime(try_cast(col as integer)) >= date '2022-08-03';
```

Output:

| col |
| --- |
| 1659648600 |

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware of try_cast().

Comment: @CaptainCaveman there is also a `try` which could be used in similar situations.